# Array Mapping in AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays

I have two **arrays**

```
$scope.tags =  [{ "id": 1, "name": "python" }, { "id": 2, "name": "NodeJs" }, { "id": 3, "name": "git" }]
```

Other one is

```
$scope.skillsInterested = [1,2];
```

What is want to do ?

**How can i map the above arrays and print only names of the id's in**`$scope.skillsInterested`

I want to print names in **first array** only the id's present in second.

I have tried this after getting several answers

```
var tag_map = {};
for (var x = 0; x < $scope.tags.length; x++) {
tag_map[$scope.tags[x]['id']] = $scope.tags[x]['name'];
}
$scope.skillsInts = $scope.skillsInterested.map(function(x) {
return tag_map[x]
```

On running console.log

```
console.log("Result", tag_map);
```

It sometimes give result sometimes it gives 'map' of undefined.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
at controllers.js:141
at angular.js:16383
at m.$eval (angular.js:17682)
at m.$digest (angular.js:17495)
at m.$apply (angular.js:17790)
at l (angular.js:11831)
at J (angular.js:12033)
at XMLHttpRequest.t.onload (angular.js:11966)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show us your `forEach` and what error you get

Comment: "Print only" means that you want to filter first array - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Comment: `$scope.tags.filter(x=>x.id === $scope.selectedExpTags )[0].name` or `$scope.tags.find(x=>x.id === $scope.selectedExpTags ).name`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make a map of your data that looks like this:

```
var tagMap = { 1: "python", 2: "NodeJs" /* etc. */ };
```

You can do this by looping over your tags and adding a new property to an object. `reduce` lets you do this without creating any extra variables.

Then, you can select names from your newly created object using the `[]` notation: `tagMap[1]` returns `"pyhton"`.

```js
var tags =  [{ "id": 1, "name": "python" }, { "id": 2, "name": "NodeJs" }, { "id": 3, "name": "git" }]
var selectedExpTags = [1,2];


// Make a map for `id: name`
var tagMap = tags.reduce(function(map, tag) {
  map[tag.id] = tag.name;
  return map;
}, {});

// Quickly select names from the map:
var selectedNames = selectedExpTags.map(function(id) {
  return tagMap[id];
});

console.log(selectedNames);
```

Using this approach, you minimise the iterations over your data. The creation of the map loops over the *tags* **once**. Creating the array with names, loops over the *selected tags* **once**. So, roughly, the "loop count" is `tags.length + selectedTags.length`. If you would use an `indexOf` based approach, your loop count would be `tags.length * selectedTags.length`.

Comment: Some times it gives the result, sometimes it throws map of undefined

Comment: selectedExpTags had to be an array

Comment: yes it is array please check the edits i have made, i have tried simple for loop and sometime it gives result and sometimes it throws error

Comment: `Cannot read property 'map' of undefined` means you have a variable that is `undefined`, and you're trying to access `.map` on it. For example: `var a = undefined; a.map();` So I'd try something like: `$scope.skillsInts = $scope.skillsInterested ? $scope.skillsInterested.map(/*etc*/) : [];`. This sets `skillsInts` to an empty array when `skillsInterested` is not defined.

Answer (score 2):

Use the filter function for `first`, and then check the id's existnent then `map` the names from the array.

```js
var first = [{ "id": 1, "name": "python" }, { "id": 2, "name": "NodeJs" }, { "id": 3, "name": "git" }];

var selectedExpTags = [1,2];

var names = first.filter(item => selectedExpTags.some(id => item.id === id)).map(item => item.name);

console.log(names);
```

Comment: `first.where is not a function"`

Answer (score 2):

You can loop over `$scope.selectedExpTags` and get a list of all names. You can use `array.find` if you want first value only.

#### Sample

```js
var first = [
  { "id": 1, "name": "python" }, 
  { "id": 2, "name": "NodeJs" }, 
  { "id": 3, "name": "git" }];

var selectedExpTags = [1,2];
var names = selectedExpTags.map(x=> first.find( y=> y.id === x ).name )

console.log(names);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$scope.newArray = []; // If you need a new array to work with
angular.forEach($scope.tags, function(tag){
$scope.selectedExpTags.forEach(function(selectedTag){ 
    if(selectedTag == tag.id){
        //tag.hide = false; // - If you want to update the current array
        $scope.newArray.push(tag);
    }
    // else{ // - If you want to update the current array
    //      tag.hide = true;
    // }
  })
})
```

**Lodash** is more efficient than angular for manipulating data.